# Unknown users in registry?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, user-accounts

I have following users in my registry.

```
s-1-5-18
s-1-5-19
s-1-5-20
S-1-5-21-3580036505-2828148361-1391708163-1001
S-1-5-21-3580036505-2828148361-1391708163-1001_Classes
```

Is it a virus or system users?

There is also a folder which contains folders of the above names and there are data files.

This folder can be deleted by shift + delete (Not only delete). Created again when something is copied / moved or deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft KB: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/243330

> SID: S-1-5-18
>   Name: Local System Description: A service account that
>   is used by the operating system.
>
> SID: S-1-5-19
>   Name: NT Authority
>   Description: Local Service
>
> SID: S-1-5-20
>   Name: NT Authority
>   Description: Network Service

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/what-relative-identifier-ends-with-1003-1003_classes.3084445/

> **SID: S-1-5-21-3580036505-2828148361-1391708163-1001**
>   * A subkey named for the Security Identifier (SID) of the current local user. This subkey contains the current user's profile. The data
>   in HKEY_USERS\SID also appears in HKEY_CURRENT_USER.
>
> **SID: S-1-5-21-3580036505-2828148361-1391708163-1001_Classes**
>   * A subkey named for the Security Identifier (SID) of the current local user with the _Classes suffix. This subkey contains the current
>   user's Classes. The data in HKEY_USERS\SID_Classes is also contained
>   in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.